# knockout how to get Parent Object in with binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

my click bind is not calling fullName funciton
  what is right way to call this ??

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="with: test.name" >
        <div>
        <span data-bind="text:firstName"></span>
        <span data-bind="text:firstName"></span>
        <br />
        <div>
        <span data-bind="click: $parent.fullName">FullName</span>
    </div>
</div>

modal = function(){
    var firstName = ko.observable('jhon'),
        lastName = ko.observable('deo'),
        test = {
            name : {
              firstName: firstName,
              lastName: lastName
           },
            fullName : function(){
                alert(name.firstName() + name.lastName());
            }
        };

    return {
        test: test
    }
}();

ko.applyBindings(modal);
```

Comment: please look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_anil/z7Fgv/14/) code

Comment: why you doin it too complex when u can do it in simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $parent meta-attribute refer to the **binding** immediately above in your binding hierarchy, not to the parent object in your view model. Since your with is in the main binding context, the $parent refers to the root view model.

If you need to access *menu* you can either nest it within another binding:

```
<div data-bind="with: test">
  <div data-bind="with: name">
  [...]
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.fullName">Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

or qualifify your call starting from the parent binding (*modal* or root binding in your example):

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.test.fullName">Click</button>
```

---

A bit of clarification regarding the binding context vs model hierarchy:

with your original binding when you apply the **with: test.name** binding, the binding context will looke like:

```
<body> <!-- binding context: [modal] -->
  <div data-bind="with: test.name"> <!-- binding context: [modal|test.name] -->
```

conversely, when applying the nested binding shown above the hierarchy changes to:

```
<body> <!-- bc: [modal] -->
  <div data-bind="with: test"> <!-- bc: [modal|test] -->
    <div data-bind="with: name"> <!-- bc: [modal|test|name] -->
```

Comment: but how can i pass Object to function i.e

<button data-bind="click: $parent.fullName(name)">Click</button>

Comment: This is a whole different issue, that has nothing to do with binding level. When a method is called from a click binding it receives the current binding target (i.e. _$data_) as parameter. You can use this in your case: `fullname: function(obj) { alert(obj.firstName+obj.lastName); }`

Answer (score 0):

Your click event should look like this:

```
<span data-bind="click: $parent.test.fullName">FullName</span>
```

I have updated you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7Fgv/16/)